# Python 3.7 \n not working in variable List[] but works for tuple() and string "" varaibles? confused

Tags: python, string, variables, tuples

So I'm a newbie working on trying to build a simple multiple choice game and I'm running into a confusing problem.

my issue is concerning the new line command \n

If I just type a simple print statement such as

```
print("Hello\nThere")
```

The new line works just fine. Likewise if create a variable string such as

```
phrase = "Hello\nThere"  
print(phrase)
```

it registers the new line just fine. I can also set the variable as a tuple ( at least i think using () creates a tuple, still new so may be wrong) such as doing

```
phrases = ("Hello There\nHow are you") 
print(phrases)
```

it also registers the new line correctly. However as soon as i try to set my variable as a list it no longer works. So if i do something like

```
phrases = ["Hello there\nHow are you"]
print(phrases)
```

it will not register the new line and just prints it out as written.

Why is this happening? Can the \n new line command not be used in variable lists? If not why? Super confused why it works for everything else but not this

Edit: ok sorry for calling it a tuple when its not. But really my question is basically why does the \n command not work when using square brackets [] but works just fine using round ones ()? I'm trying to get an understanding to the logic as to why it's not working so i can get a better grasp of this

edit2: Ok I believe I understand now. Thanks everyone for you're answers! really helped

Comment: You don't have a tuple there, there's no comma.

Comment: Printing a list prints a `repr` of each item in the list. Printing a string prints the string.

Comment: It *is* working, in both cases, it's just displayed slightly differently; inside the list you see the repr of the string, so the `\n` is shown inline.

Answer (score 1):

Because, `phrases = ("Hello There\nHow are you")` is not a tuple, it is still a string.

If you do `phrases = ("Hello There\nHow are you",)`, it becomes a tuple and will not register newline like in the list case.

You might need to get element to test for newline, like so:

```
phrases = ("Hello There\nHow are you",)
print(phrases[0])

phrases = ["Hello There\nHow are you"]
print(phrases[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [4]: phrases = ("Hello There\nHow are you")

In [5]: type(phrases)
Out[5]: builtins.str
```

I tried this in ipython, you see, ("Hello There\nHow are you") is a string rather than a tuple.

`print(["Hello there\nHow are you"])` does not really print out the string, it just tells you what is in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are printing the list itself that why you are not getting a new line but an output somewhat like this

`['Hello there\nHow are you']`

So when you are appending values or strings to a list, just iterate over the list and print

Suppose, we have a snippet as

```
phrase1="Hey there \t What's Up"
phrase2='How you doing \nEverythings is good?'
phrase3='Ok fine \n\nHave a nice day ahead!'
l=[phrase1,phrase2,phrase3]
for value in l:
    print(value)
```

So the output of this will be as

```
Hey there      What's Up
How you doing
Everythings is good?
Ok fine 

Have a nice day ahead!
```

Now here you will see that everything is working just fine!